# Anyone knows why LPAD function returns an error when it is called during UNLOAD command inside Redshift stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to call the LPAD function during the UNLOAD command inside a Redshift stored procedure and it keeps returning an error: *Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "9"* . Can anyone help me address this error?

The column that LPAD is applied to is VARCHAR data type. Basically, I'm adding leading "0" to records that are less than 9 character long.

If it matters, I'm using Aginity Pro as the query editor while connecting to Redshift. Here is an example stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schemaname.sp_example ()
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS 
   $$ 
DECLARE _CurrentDate VARCHAR(10);
           _UnloadQuery VARCHAR(65000);

   BEGIN 
   WITH CTE_CurrentDate AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'YYYYMMDD') AS CurrentDateParm)
   SELECT CurrentDateParm INTO _CurrentDate FROM CTE_CurrentDate;    

_UnloadQuery := '
          UNLOAD ('''||
                     '
                      SELECT B.column_name
    
                  FROM tbl_a a
                  INNER JOIN tbl_b B 
                  on LPAD(a.column_name,'''||$9||''',''0'') = B.column_name
              
                  GROUP BY B.column_name
                  '
              ||'''
              )


to '''||'s3://address_'||_CurrentDate||'.CSV'||'''
credentials '''||'aws_access_key_id=xxx'||';'||'aws_secret_access_key=xxx'||'''
Header
ALLOWOVERWRITE
delimiter '''||','||'''
addquotes
PARALLEL OFF
                ';
                
  EXECUTE _UnloadQuery; 

 END; 
 $$;
```